# Is leisure travel a valid reason to get a second French passport?

Tags: passports, france, french-citizens

I have an ordinary French passport, which expires in a few years. I am looking into getting a second French passport to make it possible to cross borders while my first passport is stuck in some postal service warehouse or at some embassy for visa purpose.

https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F21517 states:

> En principe, vous ne pouvez pas avoir plusieurs passe ports français. Toutefois, un second passeport peut exceptionnellement être délivré dans 2 situations : si votre passeport est immobilisé pendant une période de voyage ou si le passeport risque de faire apparaître des destinations incompatibles.

[https://translate.google.com](https://translate.google.com/?sl=fr&tl=en&text=En%20principe%2C%20vous%20ne%20pouvez%20pas%20avoir%20plusieurs%20passeports%20fran%C3%A7ais.%20Toutefois%2C%20un%20second%20passeport%20peut%20exceptionnellement%20%C3%AAtre%20d%C3%A9livr%C3%A9%20dans%202%20situations%20%3A%20si%20votre%20passeport%20est%20immobilis%C3%A9%20pendant%20une%20p%C3%A9riode%20de%20voyage%20ou%20si%20le%20passeport%20risque%20de%20faire%20appara%C3%AEtre%20des%20destinations%20incompatibles.%0A%0A&op=translate):

> In principle, you cannot have more than one French passport. However, a second passport can exceptionally be issued in 2 situations: if your passport is immobilized during a period of travel or if the passport risks showing incompatible destinations.

So my case seems to fit the first case "if your passport is immobilized during a period of travel". Must these travel be for business or in some other way compulsory, or is leisure travel a valid reason to get a second passport?

Note that 2 travels have to be considered:

1. The future travel causing the passport to be immobilized (e.g., passport stuck at embassy waiting for visa)
2. The current travel causing need to have a passport in one's pocket to cross the borders.

Therefore, I wonder whether it is ok that both travels are leisure, and if not, whether it is ok that 1 out of 2 travels is leisure and if so which one.

I am asking as https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F21517 is unclear on it. Later on the page they say "immobilized for a period during which you **must** travel" (emphasis is mine), which made me wonder whether leisure travel is ok:

> Votre passeport peut être immobilisé pendant une période au cours de laquelle **vous devez voyager**. Par exemple, le passeport peut être conservé par le consulat pour une demande de visa alors que vous en avez besoin pour voyager.

[https://translate.google.com](https://translate.google.com/?sl=fr&tl=en&text=Votre%20passeport%20peut%20%C3%AAtre%20immobilis%C3%A9%20pendant%20une%20p%C3%A9riode%20au%20cours%20de%20laquelle%20vous%20devez%20voyager.%20Par%20exemple%2C%20le%20passeport%20peut%20%C3%AAtre%20conserv%C3%A9%20par%20le%20consulat%20pour%20une%20demande%20de%20visa%20alors%20que%20vous%20en%20avez%20besoin%20pour%20voyager.&op=translate):

> Your passport may be immobilized for a period during which **you must travel**. For example, the passport can be kept by the consulate for a visa application when you need it for travel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://passeport.ants.gouv.fr/FAQ-Particulier/Questions-pratiques/Peut-on-avoir-deux-passeports):

> #### Peut-on avoir deux passeports ?
>
> Oui, il est possible d'avoir deux passeports.
>
> Vous devez vous rapprocher de la préfecture afin qu'elle vérifie les conditions de délivrance du second passeport et les pièces justificatives à joindre au dossier de demande.
>
> Le deuxième passeport est délivré en plus du passeport ordinaire dans l’un des deux cas suivants :
>
> - nécessité pour deux voyages **professionnels** concomitants ou proches dans le temps, d’immobiliser deux passeports en même temps (pour le voyage lui-même ou pour l’instruction par le consulat du pays tiers avant délivrance d’un visa).
>
>   Justificatif requis : attestation de l’employeur,
> - voyage prévu dans un pays n’acceptant pas les voyageurs munis d’un passeport doté d’un visa délivré par un État tiers identifié.  On parle alors "d’incompatibilité de visas".
>
>   Justificatif requis : production d’un passeport ordinaire doté d’un visa incompatible avec le visa à délivrer par un autre État et production d’un billet d’avion pour cet autre pays.
>   (Emphasis mine)

So, yes, both trips must be professional, with a certificate from the employer.